# I am getting "Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias' " error while starting Apache

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I want to deploy my Django project to EC2 server. I installed mod_wsgi.

And made configuration like in the tutorial of django.

I am getting the following:

```
Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What is the reason? mod_wsgi is not installed correctly?

```
LoadModule wsgi_module     libexec/httpd/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule alias_module    libexec/httpd/mod_alias.so


WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/mysite


<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user Apache runs as has read permission on `mod_wsgi.so`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error specifically indicates that mod_wsgi is not being loaded into Apache.

In what file is:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module     libexec/httpd/mod_wsgi.so
```

Did you enable the mod_wsgi module with appropriate Linux distro management command so that it will be loaded if you used distro binary packages for mod_wsgi?

Comment: For me it worked by issuing the following command: sudo a2enmod wsgi (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20627328/811335)

Answer (score 52):

The problem is that `mod_wsgi` is not installed properly.

Solution (using Apache 2):

1. install Apache:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install apache2
   ```
2. install `libapache2-mod-wsgi`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
   ```

And this should work fine.

Comment: why is the libapache2-mod-wsgi not included in the official docs? thanks so much @om choudhary

Comment: I had to install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` instead.

Answer (score 1):

just to add, How I solved my problem
if you don't know the location of the modules
just search for them

```
 locate mod_alias.so
```

then you may get output like

```
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
```

then you can add that location in your config file

```
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the very same issue on openSUSE 12.2, with apache 2.2.

Even if wsgi is installed, it is a good idea to check if it has been activated. What I mean is this:

```
#outputs a list of registered modules
/usr/sbin/httpd2 -M
```

If `wsgi_module (shared)` does not appear, add `wsgi` to the variable `APACHE_MODULES`, inside the file `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`

This way I could avoid altogether the line `LoadModule` from httpd.conf.