# Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configurationAction 'configtest' failed

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, wsgi, ckan

I got the below error while I was configuring CKAN DataPusher.

> Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server configurationAction 'configtest'
>   failed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try to enable wsgi mod in Apache

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

If you come across below error

> ERROR: Module mod-wsgi does not exist!

You will have to install mod wsgi as below. What you have to do is run the following commands,

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: At first it didn't work, but using `apt-get update --fix-missing` updated the packages and i could then install.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 to get this working with python3

Answer (score 7):

To enable wsgi_mod in httpd, install the module

```
sudo yum install mod_wsgi
```

and make sure to load the module in the httpd config file

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

then add the following line in the config file, to the list of other loaded module:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Comment: I am using windows OS, how can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry friend, I can't help you. I hope someone else will post an answer to your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I had this error after messing up my Apache installation and restarting the setup after an `apt purge apache2`. This also seems to have removed the wsgi mod but Ubuntu 20 LTS kept thinking it's still around.

So I had to to purge and reinstall the wsgi mod from scratch:

```sh
apt purge -y libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
apt install -y libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
a2enmod wsgi
```

After that, Apache was able to find it again.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem because

1. I installed mod_wsgi which was compatible with python3.5, but my project's virtual environment was using python3.7. So, mod_wsgi for 3.7 was required. I installed that as well (python3.7 -m pip install mod_wsgi). But a configuration was missing from apache2 which resulted in this issue.
2. run : **mod_wsgi-express module-config**
   add the output in /etc/apache2/apache.conf
   ( **LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
   WSGIPythonHome "/usr"** )

   then restart - sudo service apache2 restart

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add this line in your apache2.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
```

Below command will give you the above output

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```