# httpd won't start with custom conf files and mod_wsgi built with Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, apache, centos7, mod-wsgi

I am working on a RedHat Centos 7 box. I have installed python 3.9.2 into a folder under `/opt/python3.9`. I am in the midst of moving my Django server to production, and have chosen to use Apache (I have installed `httpd-devel`) with mod_wsgi. I was in the midst of following their [instructions](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html) to make sure it gets configured correctly.

I installed Apache:

```
sudo yum install httpd
sudo yum install httpd-devel
```

then

```
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/refs/tags/4.9.2.tar.gz
mv 4.9.2.tar.gz ./mod_wsgi_4.9.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz mod_wsgi-4.9.2.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi*
./configure --with-python=/opt/python3.9/bin/python39
make
sudo make install
```

all with no errors.

```
sudo systemctl enable httpd
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

But as soon as I try to use the demo [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=httpd&f=20) (which basically entails adding a conf file to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, called `wsgi.conf`, and a response file to `/var/www/html/`, called `test_wsgi.py`, then restarting Apache), it throws an error and tells me to check `journalctl -xe`.

```
Jun 08 21:04:01 ip-172-31-18-8.ec2.internal httpd[11893]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf:
Jun 08 21:04:01 ip-172-31-18-8.ec2.internal httpd[11893]: Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Jun 08 21:04:01 ip-172-31-18-8.ec2.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 08 21:04:01 ip-172-31-18-8.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 08 21:04:01 ip-172-31-18-8.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 08 21:04:01 ip-172-31-18-8.ec2.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jun 08 21:04:01 ip-172-31-18-8.ec2.internal sudo[11888]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I am 95% certain that if I did what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504280/3155240) that it would compile mod_wsgi for Python 2.7 and I don't want to use python2.7... that's why I compiled mod_wsgi for python 3.9.2.

If I try to use my django.conf file instead of the one I linked in the demo, I get a different error that might be more helpful for the slue:

```
httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Line 3 is:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Output of `ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so`:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-8 ~]$ ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd7b50d000)
        libpython3.9.so.1.0 => /opt/python39/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0 (0x00007ff0ebf85000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff0ebd4e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff0ebb30000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff0eb92c000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff0eb729000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff0eb3e9000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff0eb03e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff0ec781000)
```

I can verify that /opt/python39/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0 exists and I have it in my `LD_RUN_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables`

Output of `sudo apachectl -V`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.53 ()
Server built:   Apr 12 2022 12:00:44
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:124
Server loaded:  APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1, PCRE 8.32 2012-11-30
Compiled using: APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1, PCRE 8.32 2012-11-30
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_PROC_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error...

```
libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

...because `httpd` has no idea it's supposed to look in `/opt/python3.9/lib` to find the necessary shared library.  There are several ways of resolving this problem:

1. Set `-rpath` when linking the module.

   This embeds a path to the library in the compiled binary. You would set it by running `make` like this inside the `mod_wsgi-4.9.2` directory:

   ```
   make LDFLAGS='-L/opt/python3.9/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/python3.9/lib'
   ```
2. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `httpd`'s environment. This provides
   `httpd` with an additional list of directories to search for shared
   libraries. We can test it like this:

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/python3.9/lib httpd -DFOREGROUND
   ```

   To set it persistently, you'd want to customize the `httpd`
   service unit:

   - Run `systemctl edit httpd`
   - In the editor that comes up, add the following content:

     ```
     [Service]
     Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/python3.9/lib
     ```

     This creates
     `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/override.conf`.
   - Run `systemctl daemon-reload` to refresh the cached version of the unit file.
   - Restart your `httpd` service.
3. Edit the global library search path by creating
   `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/python3.9.conf` with the following content:

   ```
   /opt/python3.9/lib
   ```

   Then run:

   ```
   ldconfig
   ```

Any of the above options should get things running for you.

Comment: If anyone wanders across this thread: I deleted my folder that I was using for my install of mod_wsgi, uninstalled apache, reinstalled apache, httpd-devel, and then un`tar`ed, re `./configured`, make (with the LDFLAGS cmd line args), `sudo make installed`, enabled httpd, tried to do systemctl start httpd (threw an error because it was already running!?) so I used the `sudo apachectl restart` command and checked my basic wsgi.conf pag and it worked! Thank you @larsks! You have saved me from such a headache!