# Setting up django with Apache on Amazon's ec2 instance

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup Django with Apache using mod_wsgi on Amazon's ec2 instance. I was following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) guide for the setup. But after modifying the httpd.conf file and checking it with configtest,

```
/etc/init.d/httpd configtest
```

I get the following error:

```
'Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration' error.
```

The following are the lines from my httpd.conf file

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/frontend/backend-django/backend/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/ec2-user/frontend/frontendenv
WSGIPythonPath /home/ec2-user/frontend/backend-django
WSGIDaemonProcess frontend  python-home=/home/ec2-user/frontend/frontendenv python-path=/home/ec2-user/frontend/backend-django
WSGIProcessGroup frontend

<Directory /home/ec2-user/frontend/backend-django/backend>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

When I looked up at SO, I've learnt that I have to either [enable wsgi mod in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627327/invalid-command-wsgiscriptalias-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not) or  [load the module in httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947497/i-am-getting-invalid-command-wsgiscriptalias-error-while-starting-apache).

But I am getting

```
No package a2enmod available
```

and

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 159 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

errors respectively. The amazon's ec2 instance is running on **Amazon Linux**.

Comment: This may not be useful to solving the issue at hand but I find that deploying Python applications with Apache is much more difficult than things have to be. I'd recommend Gunicorn and Nginx.